# Merging Semantic Segmentation Maps with Mix Node

Tags: compositing-nodes, cryptomatte

I use Blender to generate training data for semantic segmentation of images.

The masks are generated using a Cryptomatte node. When I output the masks directly (matte.png in the image below, first file output node) this works great: I get a black and white image.
However, I want to re-color the segmentation mask (and later combine it with another), but this creates artifacts in the colored image. I tried two methods, both the color ramp and the mix node create these artifacts. The results (matte_test_1 and matte_test_2) both look correct at first glance, but when I open them in an image editing software and look at the values, they vary slightly (for example, some black pixels turn from 0,0,0 to 1,1,1). Looks like numerical imprecision or similar.

Is there a way to re-color but keep the color more precise?

Have tried both Eevee and Cycles, and Blender versions 2.93 and 3.4. I've also turned off compression on the file output nodes, but no luck.
[image]